# When is $f_n(z)= \frac{z}{z^2+n^2}$ a uniformly convergent sequence?

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Q. Find the uniform convergence region of a following complex function sequence

$$f_n(z)= \frac{z}{z^2+n^2}$$

I want to know how to find the uniform convergence region of a complex function.
It is simple when z is real, but it is very difficult when z is a complex number because of the imaginary part of z.
Finally, I want to know a strategy for finding a uniform convergence region of a general complex function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(z)=\frac{z}{z^2+n^2}$.  Evidently, the domain for $f_n(z)$ is $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\pm in\}$.

Now, note that the sequence $f_n(z)$ converges pointwise with $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(z)=0$.  Moreover, if $|z|\le R$, then we see that for $n>R$

$$\begin{align}
|f(z)|&=\left|\frac{z}{z^2+n^2}\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{|z|}{\left|n^2-|z|^2\right|}\\\\
&\le \frac{R}{n^2-R^2}\to 0
\end{align}$$

So, we see that $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on any closed disk $|z|\le R$.

We can extend the region for which $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly.  Note that if $\left|\text{Im}(z)\right|\le R$, then for $n>4R$

$$\begin{align}
|f(z)|&=\left|\frac{z}{z^2+n^2}\right|\\\\
&=\frac{|z|}{\sqrt{(|z|^2+n^2)^2-4n^2\left(\text{Im}(z)\right)^2}}\\\\
&\le \frac{|z|}{|z|^2+\frac12n^2}\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\,n}\to 0
\end{align}$$

And we see that $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly in any region for which $\left|\text{Im}(z)\right|\le R$.